# Perl get lowest number from array

Tags: json, perl

Hello i am trying to get the lowest cost here is my json

```
[
'ups_standard_international|23.63',
'ups_worldwide_saver|20.8',
'ups_worldwide_express|21.11',
'ups_worldwide_expedited|18.75',
'usps_first_class_package_international|33.43',
'usps_priority_mail_international|42.34',
'usps_priority_mail_express_international|61.79'
];
```

i want it to display
ups_worldwide_expedited|18.75

since that is the lowest cost.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: The way you want to solve this depends on whether you need to refer to the data after you find the max. If you never need to do anything other than parse it to find the max, then you don't need what is obviously a hash. If you have plenty of other accesses to the parsed values, then a hash seems ideal.

Comment: Also, by "json", do you mean this is a string? Or have you already parsed it into an array reference?

Comment: This is not a question.  It's a request for free work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hash to keep track of the lowest cost seen while iterating over your values

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $aref = [
    'ups_standard_international|23.63',
    'ups_worldwide_saver|20.8',
    'ups_worldwide_express|21.11',
    'ups_worldwide_expedited|18.75',
    'usps_first_class_package_international|33.43',
    'usps_priority_mail_international|42.34',
    'usps_priority_mail_express_international|61.79'
];

my %lowest;

foreach (@$aref) {
    my ( undef, $cost ) = split /[|]/;
    if ( !%lowest || $cost < $lowest{cost} ) {
        $lowest{cost} = $cost;
        $lowest{line} = $_;
    }
}

print $lowest{line}, "\n";
```

**EDIT:** I may have misunderstood OP's question.
If the snippet of "json" in the question is not meant to be taken as a Perl object, but rather a raw JSON string, we can use the JSON module to do basically the same, here's the updated version of the code above:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON qw(decode_json);

my $json = <<'END_JSON';
[
    'ups_standard_international|23.63',
    'ups_worldwide_saver|20.8',
    'ups_worldwide_express|21.11',
    'ups_worldwide_expedited|18.75',
    'usps_first_class_package_international|33.43',
    'usps_priority_mail_international|42.34',
    'usps_priority_mail_express_international|61.79'
]
END_JSON

# First, use double quotes to quote the strings above, to make it valid JSON:
$json =~ s/^(\s*)'([^']+)'(,?)\s*$/$1"$2"$3/gms;

# Now decode the JSON above into a perl array
my @array = @{ decode_json($json) };

# This hash will hold the element with the lowest cost
my %lowest;

# While the array still has elements, take one line from it
while ( my $line = shift @array ) {

    # Extract the cost from the line
    my ( undef, $cost ) = split /[|]/, $line, 2;

    # If this cost is the lowest we've seen yet, put it in the %lowest hash
    if ( !%lowest || $cost < $lowest{cost} ) {
        $lowest{cost} = $cost;
        $lowest{line} = $line;
    }
}

print $lowest{line}, "\n";
```

Comment: The OP is asking about a json object (text), not a Perl array.

Comment: @TLP I just went by the snippet that OP posted, and it looked to me a lot like a Perl anonymous array reference than a JSON array (JSON strings use double quotes, not single quotes, and there was a semicolon at the end).  Anyway, I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the information you'll need to do this in Perl.  It's literally 1 to 3 lines of code.  If you have specific Perl questions after that please ask a new question.

Assuming you have a JSON file or text snippet, parse it with the `JSON` module. https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON

After you have it into an array in Perl, iterate over each element with `foreach` and parse out the cost field with `split` or a regular expression.

Then simply assign the line and the cost to variables if the cost is less than the current cost.  Initialize the cost variable beforehand to something impossibly large, like 1E9.  After the loop, print out the line variable.

Here is a link to the Perl documentation.
https://perldoc.perl.org/perl#Tutorials

You'll find perlfunc and perlop especially helpful.